# How to add a Custom EqualTo To rule in jQuery.validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I had a problem getting the sum of 2 inputs to be equal to a dynamic value. In my case I needed, 2 fields to be equal to 100. I thought I'd post my solution below for anyone else who may need this as is or to make a new custom validation rule.

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but the question still needs to meet the guidelines. Eg. clear problem statement and goal to be achieved. Right now, this is close to useless.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer I got. Field1 and Field2 must be equal to 100 in the below answer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var msg;
var dynamicErrorMsg = function () { return msg; }

jQuery.validator.addMethod("equalToValue", function(value, element, param) {
    var target = parseInt($( param[0] ).val());
    var total = parseInt(value) + target;
    msg = " Field 1 and 2 must be equal to " + param[1];
    return this.optional(element) || (total == param[1]);
}, dynamicErrorMsg);

$("form").validate({
    rules: {
         field1: {
             equalToValue: ["#field2", 100]
         }
    }
});
});
```